# How to adjust the space between the algorithms and the paper text?

Tags: spacing, floats, algorithms, algorithmic

I am writing some algorithms as follow:

```
We describe some algorithms as follow:
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\caption{$A_{1}\left( x_{1} \right)$}
\STATE $y_{1} \leftarrow f\left( x_{1} \right)$
\RETURN $y_{1}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\caption{$A_{2}\left( x_{2} \right)$}
\STATE $y_{2} \leftarrow f\left( x_{2} \right)$
\RETURN $y_{2}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

Blah, blah, blah...
```

Then it looks like as follow:

[image]

The space between the paper text and algorithm is too wide, how can I adjust it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `intextsep` length

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\setlength{\intextsep}{2pt}

\begin{document}

We describe some algorithms as follow:
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \caption{$A_{1}\left( x_{1} \right)$}
        \State $y_{1} \leftarrow f\left( x_{1} \right)$
        \Return $y_{1}$
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \caption{$A_{2}\left( x_{2} \right)$}
        \State $y_{2} \leftarrow f\left( x_{2} \right)$
        \Return $y_{2}$
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

Blah, blah, blah...

\end{document}
```

[image]